# Wix: Cannot list out properties created using C# custom action

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am creating a wix installer. In some of the wxs file i have defined some properties and i am also creating some session properties inside C# custom action.

Now my requirement is to list out all session properties.
So for this i have queried **Property table** and got all properties that where defined in .wxs file.

For this i have used below custom action:

```
Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.View listBoxView = session.Database.OpenView(string.Format("select * from Property"));
            listBoxView.Execute();

            while (true)
            {
                using (Record r = listBoxView.Fetch())
                {
                    if (r == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                           Console.WriteLine(r[1].ToString(), r[2].ToString());

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it does not list out any session property that i have created using c# custom action.

Can someone help me how to list out properties that i created using c# custom action or where these properties get stored?

Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query the property table the way you do in your sample, you get only those properties defined statically in your WiX authoring, and this is expected. At install-time there's a concept called in-memory property collection - this consists out of all the properties defined in various ways: statically in Property table, provided via the command-line, system, defined in custom actions, etc.

You can access all those properties via the `Session` object. Just call `session[name]`, where `name` is the name of the property you're going to get. I doubt there's an enumerator defined for properties, but in real life you rarely need to iterate the properties - you rather try to get a certain one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my requirement is something that i have to list out all the session properties, either static or in-memory property collection. If their is some way to list them out, please let me know. I can list them out one by one but that will be very painful as i have lots of properties defined in c# code. +1 for your valuable comments but i don't have enough credit.

Comment: No, MSI only exposes MsiGetProperty and MsiSetProperty.  There is no MsiListProperties() function so while session is able to encapsulate these functions with item[string] get; set;  there is nothing to use to implement an IEnumerable off of.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround if you REALLY need to enumerate it (requires MSI 4.0 or newer):

Add full logging in the project

```
<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="Iwearucmopvx" />
```

This will log the entire installation process to your %TEMP% folder.

Then get the logfile location with:

```
var logFile = session["MsiLogFileLocation"];
```

Since the logfile is locked by the MSI logging you will have to access it in shared mode:

```
new FileStream(logFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

Read it and get the latest in-memory PROPERTY values by searching out the lines beginning with "PROPERTY CHANGE:".

```
MSI (c) (90:78) [21:07:16:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (90:78) [21:07:16:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (90:78) [21:07:16:108]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (90:78) [21:07:16:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'Employee'.
MSI (c) (90:78) [21:07:16:108]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (90!A8) [21:07:30:900]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying WEB_APP_NAME property. Its current value is '$projectname$/v1.0.0'. Its new value: '$projectname$\v1.0.0'.
MSI (c) (90!A8) [21:07:30:901]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WEB_APP_NAME_NORMAL property. Its value is '$projectname$/v1.0.0'.
MSI (c) (90!A8) [21:07:30:901]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WEB_APP_NAME_LAST property. Its value is 'v1.0.0'.
```

The drawback is that there will always be a log in the %TEMP% folder left over. Maybe add some cleaning up or something.